# Laravel eloquent multiple whereNotIn

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to make a query where I use multiple whereNotIn arrays. For some reason, they block each other and ignores the other query parameters.

Any clues on how to solve this?

```
$products = Products::orderBy('id','DESC')
    ->where('status', '=', 4)
    ->whereNotIn('category', $excluded)
    ->whereNotIn('location', ['New York', 'Boston', 'Washington, DC', 'Charlotte'])
    ->take(400)
    ->get();
```

Comment: What do you mean by *they block each other*?

Comment: For example, I get products where status is not 4, and where the category is not excluded.

Comment: OK. Use `->toSql()` instead of `->get()` and `dd` the result. It will show you what query is being run exactly.

Comment: select * from `products` where `status` = ? and `category` not in (?) and `location` not in (?, ?, ?, ?) order by `id` desc limit 400

Comment: Weird, indeed. What's the value of `$excluded`? The query itself looks fine, though.

Comment: The SQL seems correct...

Answer (score 0):

You need to group condtions `orWhereNotIn` inside `where` to exclude both condition, try this

```
$locations = ['New York', 'Boston', 'Washington, DC', 'Charlotte'];
$products = Products::orderBy('id','DESC')
->where('status', '=', 4)
->where(function($q) use ($locations,$excluded) {
    $q->orWhereNotIn('category', $excluded);
    $q->orWhereNotIn('location', $locations);
})
->take(400)
->get();
```

Comment: Even if the grouping changes anything (which I don't believe it does, as the query generated by Eloquent looks fine), I'm pretty sure the OP needs a `where` instead of `orWhere`.

Comment: @lesssugar : Let's say you want to exclude state `[Saarland,Bavaria...]` or city `[city1, city2,city3....]` but OP's query is for `[Saarland,Bavaria...]` AND city `[city1, city2,city3....]` to exclude both you need to use `orWhere`

Comment: @user2486 if that were the case, then you should change the `orWhere` in your answer to a normal `where` and make the `whereNotIn` to `or`

Comment: @Teun : you mean `whereNotIn` => `or` ? how ?

Comment: I dont know if there is a `orWhereNotIn` but you should use those if they do or else encapsulate the `whereNotIn` in an extra `orWhere`

Comment: @user2486 because now if the `status` equals 4, then both the `whereNotIn` will not be checked

Comment: OK, even if the `where not in` conditions are conflicting, none of this explains why he gets *products where status is not 4* if he specifically uses `where status = 4`.

Comment: @Teun [Yes there is](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L802).

Comment: @Tpojka :  Wow i didn't found this in doc, thanks for this

Comment: @Teun : Yes you had good point, I updated my answer. I also searched for `orWhereNotIn`

Comment: @Teun Just use [API docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/) for searching what ever you need. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is `$excluded` an array? If not you can just

```
->where('category', "<>", $excluded);
```